# Check if a function halts for all inputs

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, turing-machines

I want to write a program that checks if a function, say f halts for all values of its input. In short -

```
haltChecker = function (arg) => bool
```

e.g. in JavaScript,

```
bool haltChecker ( f(a) ){
    return {f halts for all values of a};
}
```

Solution in JS is not required, any language will do.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look much like javascript to me...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: This sounds like the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: All the answers are almost equally acceptable, but looks like Bjorn Pollex's answer exemplifies the theory. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [halting-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is undecidable. Tough luck.

To give a simple example, consider the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) (actually, this is a bad example, as it is not proven to be undecidable - but it demonstrates that the problem is hard :).

Comment: Thanks. Problem given by professor to make us understand what he taught. Things are clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

You could amaze your professor with [this](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/loopsnoop.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is also know a the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and cannot be solved in this generic form. The best you can do is to write a program which might return true if the function stops for all inputs but it also might run indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I asked really primitive problem. Thanks for trying to help though.